# Sending a variable from MYSQL to another PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to make a survey using PHP and MYSQL and cannot figure out how to send the value from the MYSQL value to another PHP page.

I am using radio buttons populated with data from the corresponding MYSQL database and when the user presses the submit button I would like to send the answer to be sent to another page so I can compare it with other answers. I have used radio buttons that I have populated myself and sent them on to another page but a just can seem to get my head around this.

So my main question would be how would you you do it? I have attempted using the `isset` function and Query Strings but once again I can do this with php variables but not with variables populated using mysql data.

The code below is what I have used to show users the question:

```
 <?php
 require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$q = "SELECT question_id, question, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4 FROM survey_db LIMIT         1";     
 $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query
if ($result) { // If it ran OK, display the records
// Table header
 echo '<table>
<tr>
<td><b> Please Answer All Questions In The Survey </b> </td>
<br>
</tr>';
// Fetch and print all the records
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '<form action="answersurvey.php" method="GET">';
echo '<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<br>
<br>

<ol><li> '.$row['question'].'</li></ol>

<input type="radio"   name = "'.$row['question_id'].'" value= "1" />'.$row['option_1'].' 
<br>
<input type="radio"   name = "'.$row['question_id'].'" value= "2" />'.$row['option_2'].' 
<br>
<input type="radio"   name = "'.$row['question_id'].'" value= "3" />'.$row['option_3'].' 
<br>
<input type="radio"   name = "'.$row['question_id'].'" value= "4" />'.$row['option_4'].' 
<br>

</td>
</tr>';
}
echo '</table>

<input type ="submit" value="submit">

</form>'; // Close the table

?>
```

Comment: How many questions are you intending to display?

Comment: @Richie I have just been displaying one question until i get it working. I hope to finally display 10 questions on one page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$q = "SELECT question_id, question, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4 FROM survey_db LIMIT         1";     
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query
if ($result) {
?>
<form action="answersurvey.php" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b> Please Answer All Questions In The Survey </b> </td>
    </tr>
<?php   
// Fetch and print all the records
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$question = $row['question'];
$question_id = $row['question_id'];
$option_1 = $row['option_1'];
$option_2 = $row['option_2'];
$option_3 = $row['option_3'];
$option_4 = $row['option_4'];
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <br>
        <br>

        <ol><li><?php echo $question;?></li></ol>

        <input type="radio"   name = "question[<?php echo $question_id;?>]" value= "1" /><?php echo $option_1;?>
        <br>
        <input type="radio"   name = "question[<?php echo $question_id;?>]" value= "2" /><?php echo $option_2;?>
        <br>
        <input type="radio"   name = "question[<?php echo $question_id;?>]" value= "3" /><?php echo $option_3;?>
        <br>
        <input type="radio"   name = "question[<?php echo $question_id;?>]" value= "4" /><?php echo $option_4;?>
    <br>

    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?></table>

<input type ="submit" value="submit">

</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

**answersurvey.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['question']))
{
    $arr_question = $_REQUEST['question'];  
    print_r($arr_question);

    foreach($arr_question as $question_id=>$option_value)
    {
         // do your task
    }
}
```